# Raising and Subscribing event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if this is even possible. I have a javascript that simply serializes the form on a page and saves it to the server on button click

```
// dispatcher script
$(function(){

    $("#btn").click(function(){

    // how to raise event here before save that another script can subscribe

    var data = $("#myform").serialize();

    //Save data here using jquery Ajax

  })
})
```

now on the same page there is one more javascript. and this javascript needs to do something before save.

```
// listener script
$(function(){       


  // in this script i want to subscribe to event and do something when event is raised

})
```

Is there a way to raise event from one javascript and subscribe in other?

*Note: for valid reasons i cannot combine both scripts into one*

I looked at [sample here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) however in my case which element subscriber would be listening on? Assume Listener script does not know `btn`.

Comment: You can use [custom events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/), but you won't be able to send the manipulated data to server, unless you want to send it twice. Guess we need more context ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do like :

```js
$(function(){
  const btn = $('#btn');
  btn.on('click',() =>{
    console.log('from one file');
    $(window).trigger('custom');
  })
  
});

$(function(){
  const btn = $('#btn');
  $(window).on('custom',() =>{
    console.log('from second file')
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me"/>
```

Comment: as i mention i cannot use specific element. Your codes triggering on specific element, in this case you are using `btn`. assume that the listener script does not know the `id` of the button or does now know anything about button

Comment: may be i need to trigger on `document`